# Grafana - Filter Variable to only show devices reported last X days

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

In Grafana, I have a variable thats been made using a Query,

```
MTR.test.*
```

This will return to me each device that has ever reported in this path.
Now, I would like to filter that data to only show devices that reported in the last X days

Is this possible?

My datasource is Graphite; the Column containing the Unix timestamp should be present in each record..